# Best practice: Text-search in Ruby, or let MongoDB do the work?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have an array of keywords, which can have a variable length. For this example imagine there are 50:

```
keywords = ['dog','cat','monkey'...'bird']
```

I have an array of sentences (again of a variable length) I want to loop through, searching for each of the keywords.

```
sentences = [ ['My dog ate cat food'], ['I went to the store.'], ... ]
```

If the sentence contains any of the keywords, then I'm moving it to a new "matched" array. So in Ruby, my code looks something like this:

```
sentences.each do |sentence|
  keywords.each do |keyword|
    if sentence.match(/\b#{keyword}\b/i)
      matched << sentence
    end
  end
end
```

This takes quite a while and seems really inefficient--especially if I have a large keyword list and a large sentence list. I'm the first to admit my Ruby development isn't that great yet--is there an easier, more efficient way to do this?

I'm using MongoDB to store the keywords and sentences. If there is a better method using the database, I'd love to explore it.

Comment: Are you looking for literal matches or full text search?

Comment: Just a literal match. "cat" instead of "catatonic" or "lolcat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used MonogDB before, but you can optimize your ruby code a bit.  Since you only care if there is a match of *any* keyword in the sentence, I would push the logic into the Ruby regexp engine:

```
regexp = keywords.map { |keyword| Regexp.quote(keyword) }.join('|')

matched = sentences.select do |sentence|
  sentence[0].match(/\\b(?:#{regexp})\\b/i)
end
```

What that does is makes one regexp that combines all your keywords.  That way you're only looping over the sentences rather than each keyword.

Comment: That worked great, I had to make a couple of little changes but I think this is much better. Thank you!

Ended up with:  
  
`matched = sentences.select do |sentence|  
 sentence[0].match(/\b(?:#{regexp})\b/i)  
end`

Comment: Excellent! Please accept the answer so others can find it as well. Best of luck with your future development! :)